# Follow the celery sample steps, always gives me the import celery error

Tags: python, celery

I followed the celery tutorial in [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html) step by step,

However after I execute the command: `celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info`, it always give me an error.

Here is the stack:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('celery==3.0.24', 'console_scripts', 'celery')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.0.24-py2.7.egg/celery/__main__.py", line 14, in main
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.0.24-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/celery.py", line 957, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.0.24-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/celery.py", line 901, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.0.24-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/base.py", line 185, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.0.24-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/base.py", line 300, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.0.24-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/base.py", line 318, in find_app
    return sym.celery
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'celery'
```

The tasks.py is just followed the sample, except that I am using redis for broker...

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379//0')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I really have no idea of what's behind this issue, could you explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fix the issue. the tasks.py should be changed as:

```
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379')

@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

By the way, is it a mistake of celery tutorial ? I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change broker url

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')
```

Note that it should be one slash before 0

**EDIT**

Or try to properly configure redis

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

Where

```
redis://:password@hostname:port/db_number
```

[Reference to docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#broker-redis)

And then call it with

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost//')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still can't work :(